# Private package was created and pip installed but cannot import with python

Tags: path, pip, package, package-managers, sys

I created a private package in TestPyPI

The package has successfully pip installed:

```
(base) my_user:Desktop$ python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps charter-common-utils==0.0.1
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
    Requirement already satisfied: charter-common-utils==0.0.1 in /Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
```

I start python in terminal:

```
>>> import charter_common_utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'charter_common_utils'
```

I've read about the python path issues but that does not seem to be the issue since the last path listed is the one referred to in the 'Requirement already satisfied' above:

```
(base) SR-C02XT71WJG5J:Desktop p2929612$ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/my_id/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

When I follow `/Users/my_id/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages'`
I am able to see the file `charter_common_utils-0.0.1.dist-info`

Why am I not able to import the package? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup.py` lists a lot of **top-level** packages:

```
    packages=['anomaly', 'batch_transform', 'hive_table_checker', 'metadata_io',
              'parquet_converter', 'pyspark_visualizer'],
```

After installation you could import `anomaly` or `parquet_converter` but not `charter_common_utils`; the latter is nowhere mentioned. To import `charter_common_utils` you have to:

1) create a new directory `charter_common_utils` at the top of your source directory (where `setup.py` resides);

2) create a new empty file `charter_common_utils/__init__.py`;

3) move all your top-level directories (`anomaly`, `batch_transform`, `hive_table_checker`, `metadata_io`, `parquet_converter`, `pyspark_visualizer`) into `charter_common_utils`;

4) change your `setup.py`:

```
    packages=['charter_common_utils',
              'charter_common_utils.anomaly',
              'charter_common_utils.batch_transform',
              'charter_common_utils.hive_table_checker',
              'charter_common_utils.metadata_io',
              'charter_common_utils.parquet_converter',
              'charter_common_utils.pyspark_visualizer',
    ],
```

Or change `setup.py` this way:

```
from setuptools import find_packages()

…

    packages=find_packages(),
```